# How to Initialize different variables (at the same time) with zeros before a for loop?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm writing a code in which I have to call the same function several times with different parameters inside a for loop. This function returns four variables and I would like to save them in a `numpy array` (matrix) for easy plotting later.

For example, let's say that I want to evaluate the functions `y = ax`, `y = x/a`, `y = ax^2` and `y = x^2/a` for different values of `a` at `x = [0, 10]`. I create a Python function to evaluate the four different functions, let's call them, `y1`, `y2`, `y3` and `y4`. I make a for loop for this and each variable would be a `numpy array`, with each column being a particular value of `a`, and each row being a particular value of `x`. The thing is that I'm required to initialize the variables before the loop and I can't find a way to do it in a simple, pretty and pythonic way.

```
import numpy as np

def func(x, a):
    y1 = a*x
    y2 = x/a
    y3 = a*x**2
    y4 = x**2/a
    return y1, y2, y3, y4

x = np.arange(0, 11)
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

y1 = np.zeros((len(x), len(a)))
y2 = np.zeros((len(x), len(a)))
y3 = np.zeros((len(x), len(a)))
y4 = np.zeros((len(x), len(a)))
for i in range(len(a)):
    y1[:, i], y2[:, i], y3[:, i], y4[:, i] = func(x, a[i])
```

I just would like to find a better way to initialize `y1`, `y2`, `y3`, and `y4`. Of course, I welcome any other advice, since I come from Matlab, this might not be the best way to do it in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a comprehension and unpack:

```
y1, y2, y3, y4 = (np.zeros((len(x), len(a))) for _ in range(4))
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you.